# Connect Raspberry PI3 3G dongle and GPS via USB

Tags: pi-3, usb, gps

I'm building a remote tracking device with a Raspberry PI3, using a Vodafone/Huawei 3g pendrive model k3765 and a
 GlobalSat G-STAR IV usb gps receiver. I'm unable to make them working properly right after the Raspberry PI is booted,
 With this  rc.local script I'm forced to add sleep 100 to postpone the execution otherwise the wdial is unable to connect to the 3G dongle.

```
(
    sleep 100
    exec /usr/bin/wvdial Defaults &
    exec /usr/sbin/gpsd /dev/ttyUSB3 -G -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
) &
```

wdial.conf defaults configuration:

```
.......
   Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
   Baud = 115200
   Init1 = ATZ
   Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 S11=55 +FCLASS=0
   .........
```

Moreover the 3G device is unable to communicate with Wvdial when initialized after the GPS:

```
[    4.492276 usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[    3.179414] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.179422] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
[    3.179430] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[    3.261904] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    3.405519] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    3.555526] brcmfmac: Firmware version = wl0: May 27 2016 00:13:38 version 7.45.41.26 (r640327) FWID 01-df77e4a7
[    3.995861] systemd-journald[142]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    4.492091] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    4.492199] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    4.492276] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    4.497753] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[    4.497874] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[    4.498008] pl2303 1-1.5:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[    4.503024] usb 1-1.5: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    4.788779] random: crng init done

[    5.355603] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[    5.487659] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1520
[    5.487692] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.487761] usb 1-1.2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[    5.487777] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
[    5.489834] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    5.490257] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[    5.608987] systemd-journald[142]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    6.182547] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    6.581231] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM Vodafone CD ROM (Huawei)  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    6.707228] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[    6.707241] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    6.708303] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    6.718098] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:6 across:2559996k SSFS
[    6.748494] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
[    6.875322] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[    6.875713] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    7.104064] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7

[   10.626059] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.626128] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   10.626134] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.626154] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.626168] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.626200] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.640867] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   10.640880] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   10.640886] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   10.641049] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   10.856795] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.856805] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.856826] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

[   11.505661] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[   11.657771] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1465
[   11.657786] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[   11.657794] usb 1-1.2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[   11.657802] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
[   11.663980] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.5: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   11.665049] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.5
[   11.666333] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.6: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   11.667116] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.6
[   11.716495] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   11.716624] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   11.717764] option 1-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.718252] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   11.718618] option 1-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.719061] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   11.719174] option 1-1.2:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.719546] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[   11.750659] cdc_ether 1-1.2:1.1 wwan0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 02:50:f3:00:00:00
[   11.751182] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   12.733814] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM  Vodafone CD ROM (Huawei)  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   12.735116] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access  Vodafone Storage (Huawei) 2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   12.738472] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   12.741085] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[   12.742362] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

I tried to unplug the GPS and reboot the Raspberry, in this way the 3G start working (notice ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttUSB2 are used):

```
[   11.496842] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[   11.628814] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1465
[   11.628829] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=3, SerialNumber                                                                            =0
[   11.628836] usb 1-1.2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[   11.628847] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
[   11.633223] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.5: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   11.633906] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.5
[   11.634483] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.6: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   11.634996] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.6
[   11.653994] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   11.654069] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   11.654137] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   11.661953] cdc_ether 1-1.2:1.1 wwan0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.u                                                                            sb-1.2, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 02:50:f3:00:00:00
[   11.662121] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   11.668099] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   11.668184] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   11.668394] option 1-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.672288] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   11.672736] option 1-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.673246] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   11.673497] option 1-1.2:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.673952] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   12.648316] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Vodafone Storage (Huawei) 2.31 PQ                                                                            : 0 ANSI: 2
[   12.650920] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Vodafone CD ROM (Huawei)  2.31 PQ                                                                            : 0 ANSI: 2
[   12.652159] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   12.679935] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   12.680268] scsi 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[   12.689555] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[   12.689561] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[   12.690131] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[   36.342198] random: crng init done
[  186.560637] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[  186.603856] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[  186.617019] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
```

Then I manually plugged the GPS:

```
[ 1656.294709] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 1656.426971] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[ 1656.426985] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1656.426993] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
[ 1656.427002] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[ 1657.488257] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[ 1657.488366] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[ 1657.488491] pl2303 1-1.5:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[ 1657.492824] usb 1-1.5: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB3
```

...and now they both works.

I need a way to make them work at boot with no delay.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your problem is that the modem and the GPS are detected in a random order on startup, yet you rely on automatically generated device names to tell them apart.

The second problem (which you resolved with a delay) is that your startup script sometimes runs before the devices are detected. The worst case detection time is theoretically very long. Even a single read operation from a disk (to load the device driver) is allowed to take up to 30 seconds, plus you could plug in additional USB devices which get detected before the modem. A fixed delay is perfectly viable in practice but not bullet-proof.

You can achieve both stable device names and device-dependent timing using a `udev` rule, e.g.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1520", SYMLINK+="/dev/modemTTY", RUN+="/usr/bin/wvdial Defaults"

ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303", SYMLINK+="/dev/gpsTTY", RUN+="/usr/sbin/gpsd /dev/gpsTTY -G -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

Note that you'll need to edit the `wvdial` config file to use the custom device name:

```
Modem = /dev/modemTTY
```

Active `udev` rules should be stored in `/etc/udev/rules.d`

Answer (score 0):

Successive exec's (is) may be contributing to the problem. Add an echo
statement after the first exec,and see if it even puts it out.

Vittal

Answer (score 0):

you better explicitly wait for a trigger file to appear. e.g.:

```
DEV=/dev/ttyUSB0
CNT=10; while [ ! -e $DEV -a $CNT -ne 0 ]; do CNT=`expr $CNT - 1`; sleep .5; done
[ $CNT -ne 0 ] && setsid sh -c '/usr/bin/wvdial Defaults' 1>&- 2>&- &
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing basically the same thing on an application of mine. I would try setting up wvdial as a systemd service and set it so that it restarts time after time if it fails with **Restart=always** and **RestartSec=60** or something like that.